STOLE MY WALLET
I've been hacked and my email account was compromised, leading to the theft of my cryptocurrency wallets. I know this is a rookie mistake, but I'd like to know if there's a Solana developer who could help me flag this fraudulent transaction and the compromised wallet. Ideally, I'd like to recover my cryptocurrencies
this is the transaction
https://solscan.io/tx/5iAKNexGMFJhfz2B4YwbnosDezQswVzmTHr7KMm2D6nF19HQigKje31o9sHp5JSPPumwhsmd7dtHooJtATKVS7QK
